# Programatically add LinearLayout in fragment with padding between buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to know how to add or link with findviewID a LinearLayout with multiple buttons (programatically added) and space between them. I have tried to create a XML layout in my fragment and link it to a variable of the type LinearLayout and work from there with LayoutParams but I don't get it to work properly. I would like to know if anyone here has any suggestions. below is my code.

```
private GuiLoader guiloader = new GuiLoader();
private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_list_fragment, container, false);
    layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2.0f);
    param.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
    layout.setPadding(500, 86, 50, 50);
    layout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

and the button creation throug a class

```
for (final VideoDevice videoDevice : videoDevices) {
        Button myButton = guiloader.createButton(getActivity());
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        myButton.setText(videoDevice.description);
        layout.addView(myButton, guiloader.buttonWidth, guiloader.buttonHeight);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you call setPadding and setLayoutParams on your LinearLayout - this deals with the padding/margins around the edges of the LinearLayout - not between the buttons.

It sounds like you would like to have a gap between the buttons. For that, you can:

1) add a margin to each button inside your for loop

2) consider using [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) which allows you to specify the spacing between children using android:horizontalSpacing and android:verticalSpacing

Comment: Thank you for awnsering my question, when I change my LinearLayout to gridview I cannot use it anymore in my for loop and which button command would I use to set the Margin because none is listed.

Comment: You could to add this inside your for loop:

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    param.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(param);`